# Not able to invoke Remote Actor

Tags: scala, akka

I wrote this code to create a remote actor

```
object Main extends App {
  val system = ActorSystem("keyvalue")
  system.actorOf(Props[KeyValueActor], name = "keyvalue-db")
}

class KeyValueActor extends Actor {
  val map = new util.HashMap[String, Object]
  val log = Logging(context.system, this)

  override def receive = {
    case SetRequest(key, value) => {
      log.info(s"received set request key ${key} value ${value}")
      map.put(key, value)
      sender() ! Status.Success
    }
    case GetRequest(key) => log.info(s"recieved get request ${key}")
      sender() ! KeyValue(map.get(key))
    case _=> log.info("unknown message")
  }
}
```

I started my server using `activator run` and this printed the message

```
[info] Running com.abhi.akka.Main
[INFO] [01/10/2016 20:21:52.461] [run-main-0] [Remoting] Starting remoting
[INFO] [01/10/2016 20:21:52.617] [run-main-0] [Remoting] Remoting started;
listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://keyvalue@127.0.0.1:2552]
[INFO] [01/10/2016 20:21:52.619] [run-main-0] [Remoting] 
Remoting now listens on addresses: [akka.tcp://keyvalue@127.0.0.1:2552]
```

but now when i try to call my remote actor using this client code

```
object KeyValueClient {

  def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = {
    implicit val system = ActorSystem("LocalFileSystem")
    implicit val timeout = Timeout(2 seconds)
    val keyValueActorRef = system.actorSelection("akka.tcp://keyvalue@127.0.0.1:2552/user/keyvalue-db")
    keyValueActorRef ! SetRequest("foo", "bar")
    (keyValueActorRef ? GetRequest("foo")).onSuccess({
      case x : KeyValue => println(s"got value ${x.value}")
    })
  }
}
```

it throws an error message

```
[INFO] [01/10/2016 20:25:33.345] [LocalFileSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka://LocalFileSystem/deadLetters] Message [com.abhi.akka.messages.SetRequest] from Actor[akka://LocalFileSystem/deadLetters] to Actor[akka://LocalFileSystem/deadLetters] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
[INFO] [01/10/2016 20:25:33.346] [LocalFileSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka://LocalFileSystem/deadLetters] Message [com.abhi.akka.messages.GetRequest] from Actor[akka://LocalFileSystem/temp/$a] to Actor[akka://LocalFileSystem/deadLetters] was not delivered. [2] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
```

My Full code is available at

https://github.com/abhitechdojo/keyvaluedb.git

https://github.com/abhitechdojo/keyvalueclient.git

EDIT: I solved the problem based on the suggestion given by Mustafa Simov. The client side needed this configuration file

```
akka {
  actor {
    provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
    deployment {
      /keyvalue-db {
        remote = "akka.tcp://keyvalue@127.0.0.1:2552"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you create the actor using

```
val actor = system.actorOf(Props[KeyValueActor], "keyvalue-db")
```

Comment: Are you running them on the same machine?

Comment: yes... but learning akka-remote. other approaches like creating actor locally with props work without any issues. I want to make akka-remote work

Comment: just checking that it's not a firewall or wrong IP issue. You code looks fine, so try telnet to check your port connectivity ;)

Comment: You can set logging to debug - perhaps you'll see more errors

Comment: try `telnet 127.0.0.1 2552` from the machine where you are running the client. On Windows firewall might block apps like Java, so check that as well.

Comment: I am using macbook pro and I checked that firewall is off. I can also telnet into 127.0.01 2552

Comment: The client does not compile: com.abhi#akkatest_2.11;1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: not found. You need to add a resolver or publish your jar?

Comment: you need to publish the server jar to local maven using `activator publish-local` then the client will compile.

Comment: Can you post a copy of your akka conf files?

Comment: My conf file is here https://github.com/abhitechdojo/keyvaluedb/blob/master/src/main/resources/application.conf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have looked at your client code and I think it is just a configuration problem. In order to use akka-remoting, you must configure your client too. So you must create an `application.conf` for client ActorSystem as you created for server.

Answer (score 0):

Akka remoting is peer-to-peer and [not really a good fit for client-server](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.1/general/remoting.html#Peer-to-Peer_vs__Client-Server)

Because of this both sides in remoting must be able to connect to the other side, as either of them can initiate communication. Both of your applications therefore needs to configure a remoting actor-ref provider and host+port pair that the other node can connect through. You can read [details about how to do this in the akka docs here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.1/scala/remoting.html#Preparing_your_ActorSystem_for_Remoting).